# How do i get the print outs to show up correctly under the final output

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, formatting

Im trying to create a chart for radii that the output looks like this.

```
Radius           Area            Circumference
1.000             3.142           6.283
2.000             ....            ....
```

this is what I keep getting

```
 radius     area     circumference
   1        3.142     6.283
 radius     area     circumference
    2        ...       ....
```

The issue im having is is that my code is outputting the words radius area and circumference  with each line im not sure how to fix this.

```
    def main():
    x = ("radius")
    y = 'area'
    z = 'circumference'


for Radius in range(1 , 11):
    round (3)

    Area = (Radius)**2*3.14
    Circumference =  (Radius)*2*(3.14)
    a = Radius
    b = Area
    c = Circumference

    x = ("radius")
    y = 'area'
    z = 'circumference'
    print ('radius   area     circumference')
    print ('{:2d}    {:10.3f}   {:10.3f}'.format(a, (b), (c)))
```

Comment: You don't need to round if you are using formatting instead. Why did you use `d` for the radius when you wanted to display a value with decimals?

Comment: In what way(s) is you code deficient?

Comment: I have edited it to show what the problem is.

Comment: Is your indenting here really the way your code is?

Comment: Also what is the purpose of the variables `x`, `y`, and `z`? And why are they duplicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `print ('radius   area     circumference')` is inside your for loop, it is repeated every time you loop. Instead, you should put this line **before** the loop to print out your headers once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print('{:10}{:10}{:10}'.format('radius', 'area', 'circumference'))
print('{: <10}{: <10.3f}{: <10.3f}'.format(1, 2.2, 3))
```

from the docs

```
 '{:<30}'.format('left aligned')
 'left aligned                  '
 '{:>30}'.format('right aligned')
 '                 right aligned'
 '{:^30}'.format('centered')
 '           centered           '
 '{:*^30}'.format('centered')  # use '*' as a fill char
 '***********centered***********'
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings